# How to get FD on datagram socket?

Tags: java, udp, file-descriptor, datagram

Before java 17, we could get the FD on a datagram socket like below trick with reflection, in order to set a socket option for SO_PORTREUSE using a kernel API.  But the implementation changed in latest java and the field is now called delegate, and the setAccessible API will not work with it due to a java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException.

Has anyone found an alternative way to get this from the datagram socket?

```
    private int getFD(DatagramSocket ds) throws Exception {
        Field dsImpl = DatagramSocket.class.getDeclaredField("impl");
        dsImpl.setAccessible(true);

        Field fd = DatagramSocketImpl.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
        fd.setAccessible(true);

        FileDescriptor fdi = (FileDescriptor) fd.get(dsImpl.get(ds));

        Field fdVal = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
        fdVal.setAccessible(true);

        return fdVal.getInt(fdi);
    }
```

Comment: Eh? You can already set SO_REUSEPORT with [`DatagramSocket.setOption()` and `SO_REUSEPORT`](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~cs212/javadoc/api/java.base/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html#SO_REUSEPORT). You don't need Reflection at all.

Answer (score -2):

It appears that using the opens JVM flags we can get this work with java 17 again.

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Private fields are private for a reason.  They are implementation details.  Any future release of Java is free to change or remove them.  Java has warned people for many years not to rely on such internals.